# I'm not sure if I have written my SQL query properly for the question

Tags: mysql, sql

This is not a real database so there is no information other than what I listed here.

3 tables

```
movie 
(
  MID varchar(8),
  title varchar(50),
  primary key (MID)
);

actor
(
  AID  varchar(8), 
  name varchar(30), 
  salary numeric(8, 2), 
  primary key (AID)
);

actor_role
( 
  MID varchar(8), 
  AID varchar(8), 
  rolename varchar(20), 
  primary key (MID,AID),
  foreign key (MID) references movie(MID),
  foreign key (AID) references actor(AID)
);
```

---

I have to write a query for this question-

1. Find all actors' name who has had a role in movies (Remove duplicates).

Here is what I have written. Have a done it correctly?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT name, rolename
FROM movie
JOIN actor_role
ON actor_role.MID = movie.MID
JOIN actor
ON actor_role.AID = actor.AID;
```

Comment: Have you run it? If you have, you should be able to tell if it works or not. If you haven't, you need to do so. Your instructor will tell you if you've done it correctly, because only that instructor knows what they are expecting from the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work. No promises without trying it with real data.

But you want to do two more things to make it robust.

First, the wise query writer, when joining tables, qualifies all column names with table names. Like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT actor.name, actor_role.rolename
FROM movie
JOIN actor_role
ON actor_role.MID = movie.MID
JOIN actor
ON actor_role.AID = actor.AID;
```

Second, when a query uses SELECT DISTINCT it's often a sign of strange data, or of the query writer misunderstanding the data.  Your query is very close to this one.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) number_of_movies, actor.name, actor_role.rolename
FROM movie
JOIN actor_role
ON actor_role.MID = movie.MID
JOIN actor
ON actor_role.AID = actor.AID
GROUP BY actor.name, actor_role.rolename
```

If you have, for example, one row for each episode of [The Mandolorian](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8111088/) you'll get

```
24   Pedro Pascal  The Mandolorian
12   Barry Lowin   The Mandolorian
```

without showing the values of `movie.title`, presumably the name of the episode.  SELECT DISTINCT gets you the same aggregated result but without the COUNTs. If that's what you want go right ahead and use SELECT DISTINCT.  But, if I were your co-worker I'd appreciate a comment in your code explaining why DISTINCT.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I am missing, the actor.name, actor_role.rolename. The reason I used distinct is that she wanted us to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

By joining all tables you only get actors who played a role in a film. You are showing all actors and their roles without duplicates. This looks good. You can remove the movie table from the from clause, though. It is not needed.

If the task is meant to just show actors who played some role, however, then you can simply remove rolename from the select clause.

When working with multiple tables you should qualify all columns, though. This gets the query safer in case tables change. So `SELECT DISTINCT actor.name, actor_role.rolename ...`.

For tasks where we just want to look whether a row exists, I prefer `EXISTS` and `IN` over joins. After all we want to select actors who played some role in a movie. That is:

```
select *
from actor
where aid in (select aid from actor_role);
```

Thus you don't have to remove any duplicates.

Comment: If I remove the movie table from the from clause, do I need to replace it with actor?

Comment: No, actor is already in your from clause. Just `SELECT DISTINCT actor.name, actor_role.rolename FROM actor_role JOIN actor ON actor_role.aid = actor.aid;`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understand what I need to do now.